# DB Null conversion

Tags: c#, sql, dbnull

I have written a relatively big insert statement, and some of the fields are null.

I cannot convert from db null to other types and I don't really want to check Convert.IsDBNull for every single item

What should I do?

```
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand iCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Insert into ProductCode values('" +
                    greader["CODE"].ToString() +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE01"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE02"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE03"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE04"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE05"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE06"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE07"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE08"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE09"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE10"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE11"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE12"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE13"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE14"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE15"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE16"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE17"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE18"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE19"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE20"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE21"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE22"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE23"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE24"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE25"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE26"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT01"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT02"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT03"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT04"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT05"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT06"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT07"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT08"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT09"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT10"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT11"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT12"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT13"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT14"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT15"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT16"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT17"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT18"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT19"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT20"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT21"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT22"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT23"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT24"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT25"]) +
                    "','" + Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT26"]) +
                    "')", iConnect);
```

Comment: without doing in every item, do you expect to have it implemented in Convert.ToDouble and Convert.ToChar ?

Comment: Definitively, use Parameters!

Comment: Why don't you do something like `Convert.ToDouble(greader["DISC_PCT05"])  ?? 0`

Comment: @justin kirk: If you want your application to be solid you need to check for null conditions and if needed use stored procedure so that application does not have any sql injection problems

Comment: oh wow, people on this form are so childish lol,... as if that's a bad question, i simply assumed there would be an easier way then checking for every single item ...

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum. Nor a form. FYI

Comment: Database normalization, parameters usage required. After that your work should be easier and you won't need to check so much items.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a form AND a forum, anyway, thank you Ivan Crojach, that seems simple enough to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without analysing why you're using the above method, I'd simply write my own method to do this. Simply write your own `Convert.ToChar` and `Convert.ToDouble`, something like this:

```
public class MyConvert
{
    public static char ToChar(object value, char defaultValue)
    {
        return Convert.IsDBNull(value) ? defaultValue : Convert.ToChar(value);
    }
}
```

So rather than having a `Convert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE01"])` you would use `MyConvert.ToChar(greader["DISC_CODE01"], '')`. Do the same for double as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, object> greaderDic = new Dictionary<string,object>();
foreach(var item in greader.Items/*or whatever you have to enumerate your greader*/)
{
greaderDic.Add(item.Name, GetValue(item.Name, item.Value));// hope you have something like Name or Value properties
}

object GetValue(string name, objetc value)
{

if (name.StartsWith("DISC_CODE"))
return value == null? "NULL" : Convert.ToChar(value)

if (name.StartsWith("DISC_PCT"))
return value == null? "NULL" : Convert.ToDouble(value);

throw new Exception("Mapping not found for " + item.Name);

}
```

Additionally replace in old code all `greader` tokens by `greaderDic`